# Why is BH not used as an argument in the BIOS teletype function (`ah=0Eh` `int 10h`)?

Tags: assembly, virtualbox, interrupt, x86-16, bios

The interrupt `ah=0Eh` `int 10h` displays a character on the screen, it has several parameters including BH, which is supposed to indicate the page number, except that after several tests I realized that BH is absolutely useless. Even if I change the page number the character will still display on the active page no matter what.

[Ralf Brown's interrupt list says](https://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm)

> "IBM PC ROMs dated 1981/4/24 and 1981/10/19 require that BH be the same as the current active page"

And a page on the internet puts this : [https://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/mc404-2004/service_interrupts#int10h_0Eh](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/%7Ecelio/mc404-2004/service_interrupts#int10h_0Eh)

> This functions displays a character on the screen, advancing the cursor and scrolling the screen as necessary. The printing is always done to current active page.

I have to trust which source, I use virtual box without operating system, and I use a bootloader program.

I specify that I do not understand this information

> IBM PC ROMs dated 1981/4/24 and 1981/10/19 require that BH be the same as the current active page

Knowing that I use virtual box, I do not think that virtual box uses ROMs from IMG PCs dating from 1981?

Comment: [techhelp](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/129-int_10h_0eh__write_character_as_tty.html) doesn't mention `BH` to be a page number for int 10h function 0Eh. TTY has no pages. Functions family 13h uses `BH` as a page number.

Comment: @dimich : On the iBM PC ROMs TTY was output to the current active page. In ThE IBM-PC rom source Int 10h/ah=0eh (14d) is documented as *(AH) = 14 WRITE TELETYPE TO ACTIVE PAGE* https://github.com/jeffpar/pcjs/blob/master/machines/pcx86/ibm/5150/rom/bios/1982-10-27/src/PCBIOSV3.ASM#L3459C11-L3459C11

Comment: @MichaelPetch That confirms what i know: TTY interface is simulated by writting to an active page, no need to set `BH` before call. Maybe ROM versions mentioned by OP contained bug, and `MOV BH,ACTIVE_PAGE` was absent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Service `ah = 0x0E`, `int 0x10` only prints on active page. You can change active page using service `ah = 0x05`, `al = page number`, `int 0x10`.

BH isn't supposed to be an input to this BIOS function.  Ralf Brown's interrupt list only shows it as part of documenting the bug in the two early IBM-PC BIOS versions it mentions (1981/4/24 and 1981/10/19) where BH needs to hold the active page number.  Otherwise it's not an input at all.

---

I looked at the code of BIOS 1981-04-24, 1981-10-19 and 1982-10-27 and the service `ah = 0x0E` (*write_tty*) in the first two BIOSes starts like this:

> ```
> WRITE_TTY PROC    NEAR
>   PUSH    AX      ; SAVE REGISTERS
>   PUSH    AX      ; SAVE CHAR TO WRITE
>   MOV AH,3
>   INT 10H         ; READ THE CURRENT CURSOR POSITION
>   POP AX          ; RECOVER CHAR
>
>   . . .
>
> ;------ WRITE THE CHAR TO THE SCREEN
>
>   MOV BH,ACTIVE_PAGE  ; GET THE CURRENT ACTIVE PAGE
>   MOV AH,10       ; WRITE CHAR ONLY
>   MOV CX,1        ; ONLY ONE CHAR
>   INT 10H
> ```

There is service `ah = 0x03` (*read_cursor*) at the beginning which needs `bh = page number` to calculate offset to cursor position on active page, this value is returned in DX and stored here:

> ```
>   CURSOR_POSN DW  8 DUP(?)    ; CURSOR FOR EACH OF UP TO 8 PAGES
> ```

And later we have instruction `mov bh,active_page`. For example we want to write to page 0, we calculate cursor position on page 0, but active_page = 1 so we have mismatch. So maybe that's why RBIL page talk about it, BH should be same as active_page.

> IBM PC ROMs dated 1981/4/24 and 1981/10/19 require that BH be the same as the current active page

In last BIOS 1982-10-27, line `MOV BH,ACTIVE_PAGE` changed position

> ```
> WRITE_TTY PROC    NEAR
>   PUSH    AX          ; SAVE REGISTERS
>   PUSH    AX          ; SAVE CHAR TO WRITE
>   MOV AH,3
>   MOV BH,ACTIVE_PAGE      ; GET THE CURRENT ACTIVE PAGE
>   INT 10H         ; READ THE CURRENT CURSOR POSITION
>   POP AX          ; RECOVER CHAR
> ```

BH is same as active_page. So program calculates position for correct page.

---

Here's an example of using it in a BIOS MBR bootloader. This works well in QEMU:

```
[org 0x7C00]

section .text
    global main

main:   
    mov ax,0
    mov ds,ax
    mov ss,ax
    mov sp,0x7C00

    mov ax,0x0003
    int 0x10

    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov si, msg1    
    
Msg_1:
    lodsb                
    or al,al
    jz WaitKeyPress1
    int 0x10        
    jmp Msg_1

WaitKeyPress1:
    mov ah,0x00
    int 0x16
    
    mov ah,0x05
    mov al,0x01
    int 0x10
    
    mov ah,0x0E
    mov si,msg2
    
Msg_2:
    lodsb                
    or al,al
    jz WaitKeyPress2
    int 0x10        
    jmp Msg_2   

WaitKeyPress2:
    mov ah,0x00
    int 0x16
    
    mov ah,0x05
    mov al,0x00
    int 0x10

Done:   
    jmp Done

msg1 db "This message is printed on page 0."
        db 13,10,"Press any key to change page to 1...",0
    msg2 db "And this message is printed on page 1."
        db 13,10,"Press any key to go back to page 0.",0

    
    times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
    dw 0xAA55
```

This works from the command line, as a DOS .COM:

```
[org 100h]
    
section .data
    msg1 db "This message is printed on page 0."
        db 13,10,"Press any key to change page to 1...",0
    msg2 db "And this message is printed on page 1."
        db 13,10,"Press any key to go back to page 0.",0
        

section .text
    global main

main:   
    mov ax,0x0003
    int 0x10

    mov ah, 0x0E  
    mov si, msg1    
    
Msg_1:
    lodsb                
    or al,al
    jz WaitKeyPress1
    int 0x10        
    jmp Msg_1

WaitKeyPress1:
    mov ah,0x08
    int 0x21
    
    mov ah,0x05
    mov al,0x01
    int 0x10
    
    mov ah,0x0E
    mov si,msg2
    
Msg_2:
    lodsb                
    or al,al
    jz WaitKeyPress2
    int 0x10        
    jmp Msg_2   

WaitKeyPress2:
    mov ah,0x08
    int 0x21
    
    mov ah,0x05
    mov al,0x00
    int 0x10

Done:   
    mov ax,4C00h
    int 21h
```

Comment: So why does RBIL document BH as a page-number input at all?  Is that just part of documenting the bug(?) in those two 1981 IBM-PC BIOS versions that require BH set to the active page number?

Comment: I don't know, maybe it's just a mistake. Doesn't matter what value is in `bh` because `write_tty proc` has this instruction `mov bh, active_page` and `active_page` is set to 0 in `set_mode proc` or can be changed in `act_disp_page proc`, `mov active_page, al`.

Comment: Interesting detective work on those old BIOSes.  I edited your answer to actually put an answer at the top, not buried in the middle.  Remember, future readers that want an answer to the question will start reading at the top, so put at least a TL:DR there, with details and side-notes later.

Comment: In older BIOS source (I was looking at the [August 1981 Technical Reference Manual](https://bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/pc/pc/6025008_PC_Technical_Reference_Aug81.pdf)), the block comment on page A-44, which documents all the INT 10h functions, claims that AH=14 does take the page in BH.  As you note, this didn't actually work because they do `MOV BH,ACTIVE_PAGE` partway through the function.  Rather than fix the bug, it appears they just gave up on that feature; later versions (I looked at the PC-AT) describe the function as "write teletype to active page", and initialize BH as you saw.